# Site to release open source project

Tags: open-source

I have an open source project, which currently is stored in github and up to now I've been pleasured with this. However, Github has a poor functionality for releasing standalone applications, so I'm looking for something more.

In future I'm going to share my application with many peoples and I'd like to use a site, which allows releasing open-source projects and has the following sections:

- Feedback - reviews of people
- Likes - Stars 4/5, 3/5 or somewhat
- Download counters for different versions
- Comprehensive for any user (newbie, old people, etc) system of downloading - like - "Select OS"  - "Download"

What are the most popular sites, which apply to all (or at least 3 and 4 p.) my requirements?

Comment: Please note that website recommendations are off-topic here (see: [Can I ask for recommended websites?](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/191/185)), same applies to hosting (see: [Are hosting recommendation requests on-topic?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/675/185)). There's a proposal for [Website Recommendations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80273/website-recommendation) at Area51 which you might wish to support, as currently this is not covered by any SE site.

Comment: @Izzy, it's really lame, that SE doesn't let recommending websites. I'm not asking for "the best", I just look for all available resources.
BTW, In your link to Area51 - "This proposal has been deleted.
Inactive proposals that do not receive any activity for one month are subject to deletion"

Comment: You're asking for a site (website) to host your project. As pointed out, that's off-topic here: SR is about recommending ***software*** meeting specific requirements, not websites, services, hosters, providers, etc. Each SE site has its specific scope and, no offense meant, your question is not within the scope of this site.

Comment: That proposal was deleted, but the identically named proposal http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92540/website-recommendations is still there (note different id number).

Answer (score 0):

I Never released an open source with it, but i used to get many open source software from it!

You can have a look to [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/). It seems to fit all of your requests

From the Sourceorge FAQ:

*"SourceForge is a free hosting service for Open Source developers which offers, among other things, a CVS repository, mailing lists, bug tracking, message forums, task management software, web site hosting, permanent file archival, full backups, and total web-based administration."*

and maybe you can read more about it from [here](http://newbiedoc.sourceforge.net/metadoc/sourceforge-guide.html).

Comment: Sourceforge has lost a lot of its reputation over the past few years, and today is better known for its dubious practices of e.g. bundling bloatware with installers if your software is for Windows (a reason why many projects like Gimp took their software away from that site). This might change again, with [its new ownership since 1/2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SourceForge#2016_Acquisition) (see [FossForce](http://fossforce.com/2016/01/sourceforge-and-slashdot-have-been-sold/)).